# SAS RegEx String Extraction

Tags: regex, sas, extract

I have a vector of strings where each observation has a bunch of random text. For example:

```
  "SOLAR MARS T-1500S TURBINE (13,300-BHP, NG, CENTRIFUGAL)"
  "13-A, C-B, 1350 HP, NATURAL GAS COMPRESSOR ENGINE"
  "3,000HP KVT-512 ENGINE"
  "Engine 1, Caterpillar G3512 TALE : Emission Point:"
  "DRESSER RAND - 2SLB ENGINE 1 RATED AT 3,200 BHP"
  "Clark Engine #1 - 1550 HP natural gas-fired SI 2SLB"
  "E1 - s/n WPW-01669 JJJJ""
```

I am trying to extract the horsepower values (any 4-5 five digit number followed by either "BHP" or "HP").  Note, some observations do not have any HP value.  Ultimately I want to return the following:

```
  13,330-BHP
  1350HP
  3,000HP
  .
  3,200 BHP
  1550 HP
  .
```

I don't have much experience using Regex in SAS.  Do anyone have any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: Here's a regex that should work for it: `(\d+(,\d+)*[ -]?B?HP)`
Although I don't know how to use SAS's regex features.

Answer (score 2):

Converting comment by @Zachary Haber to code.

First convert the text into an actual SAS dataset.

```
data have;
  input string $80.;
cards;
SOLAR MARS T-1500S TURBINE (13,300-BHP, NG, CENTRIFUGAL)
13-A, C-B, 1350 HP, NATURAL GAS COMPRESSOR ENGINE
3,000HP KVT-512 ENGINE
Engine 1, Caterpillar G3512 TALE : Emission Point:
DRESSER RAND - 2SLB ENGINE 1 RATED AT 3,200 BHP
Clark Engine #1 - 1550 HP natural gas-fired SI 2SLB
E1 - s/n WPW-01669 JJJJ
;
```

Now read in that dataset and use CALL PRXNEXT() to find the first match.  Added code to also convert the result into a number.

```
data want;
  set have;
  if _n_=1 then regexid = prxparse('(\d+(,\d+)*[ -]*?B?HP)');
  retain regexid;
  drop regexid;
  length want $40;
  start=1;
  stop=length(string);
  call prxnext(regexid,start,stop,string,position,len);
  want=substrn(string,position,len);
  HP = input(compress(want,',- BHP'),??32.);
run;
```

Result:

```
Obs       want         HP     string

 1     13,300-BHP    13300    SOLAR MARS T-1500S TURBINE (13,300-BHP, NG, CENTRIFUGAL)
 2     1350 HP        1350    13-A, C-B, 1350 HP, NATURAL GAS COMPRESSOR ENGINE
 3     3,000HP        3000    3,000HP KVT-512 ENGINE
 4                       .    Engine 1, Caterpillar G3512 TALE : Emission Point:
 5     3,200 BHP      3200    DRESSER RAND - 2SLB ENGINE 1 RATED AT 3,200 BHP
 6     1550 HP        1550    Clark Engine #1 - 1550 HP natural gas-fired SI 2SLB
 7                       .    E1 - s/n WPW-01669 JJJJ
```